# FileReader issue in IOS8 Safari

Tags: javascript, safari, ios8, filereader

One of our webpage does image processing before sending it to server. Our code basically takes selected image via file upload and pass on to FileReader to get image binary string.

```
 var reader = new FileReader(); 
 reader.onload  = function(event) {
 var img = new Image();
    img.src = this.value;
     ....
 }
 reader.readAsDataURL(referanceToFile);
```

Above code works fine on predecessors of IOS 8 Safari and after upgrade to IOS 8,

- onload event of FileReader is not firing.
- onloadend event is firing but unable to read the file content.

No luck with any workarounds. If any one experienced similar issues, please share your thoughts and potential solutions.

Thanks in advance

Mahesh